# Links with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have the following code in my controller:

```
# encoding: utf-8
module Admin

  class SylabusController < BaseController


  def show_all
      @questions = @topic.questions.all
    end
```

And I have the index where I would like to "call" the show_all in order that appears a new web page with all the questions. How does be the link?

```
 <%= link_to 'All the questions'.html_safe, @sylabus.show_all, class: 'btn' %>
```

With the following error.

```
NoMethodError in Admin/mupets#index

Showing app/views/admin/sylabus/index.html.erb where line #41 raised:

undefined method `show_all' for nil:NilClass
```

Is it my error in the link code? or Do I have to define something in the routes?

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: What does your routes file look like?  Also, where are you setting the value of @topic?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot link directly to actions on controllers, you can only make requests which are connected to a controller/action via your routing table.

You need a route which will reach that action, and then you need a view which will render output to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your quickly answer. Therefore if I want to link anything. Do I have to link using routes? Sorry if my question is very "newbie" but  I am coming from php and rails is really different :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your `SylabusController`:

```
def index
   # are you sure that @topic is not null?
   @questions = @topic.questions
end
```

In your view

```
 <%= link_to 'All the questions', @questions, class: 'btn' %>
```

Just get class variable associateded with controller action :)